# Custom Forms Authentication reporting Services 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have implemented the sample forms authentication  for sql server2008 r2.. I am able to create the users and when i logging with the database user which in the table it i am getting this error..

Can anyone please help..

```
ui!ReportManager_0-1!13bc!10/04/2011-12:15:33:: e ERROR: Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderPage+InsufficientPermissionsToRoot: User '' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderPage.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
library!ReportServer_0-2!1ec4!10/04/2011-12:15:33:: Call to GetSystemPermissionsAction().
ui!ReportManager_0-1!13bc!10/04/2011-12:15:33:: e ERROR: HTTP status code --> 500
-------Details--------
Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderPage+InsufficientPermissionsToRoot: User '' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderPage.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
library!ReportServer_0-2!1ec4!10/04/2011-12:15:33:: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
ui!ReportManager_0-1!13bc!10/04/2011-12:15:33:: e ERROR: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path, Boolean preserveForm)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ShowErrorPage(String errMsg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a permissions issue.  I would look towards the user that is used for the service as well as hitting the database.  Maybe you have it set to an anonymous connection?

Comment: Thanks for the update. In the forms authentication i am registering the user then i am logging with that user..for example that will be name 'xxxx' having access to site manager and for certain reports..There are normal users and admin user normal user is having access to certain reports... and when i log in with the normal user it is giving me above error.

Comment: anonymous connection to the database would you please give me steps by step guide...please